# Displaying Map on Lwuit nokia s40

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40, lwuit-form, here-api

I'm using Lwuit to develop app on nokia s40 SDK 2.0
I have to add a Map to my application..
So i hav used the code given below but the screen doesnot display anything.
I get a blank screen. How can I display this on lwuit form or container?
(the code runs completely and exits without errors & 'END' is printed)

> ApplicationContext.getInstance().setAppID("ruKXq--------Sbgq");
>             ApplicationContext.getInstance().setToken("kWRp_Vp---------AG7rw");
>
> ```
>       Display display = Display.getDisplay(COMPANY_Midlet.getInstance());
>       MapCanvas mapCanvas = new MapCanvas(display) {
>           public void onMapUpdateError(String description, 
>               Throwable detail, boolean critical) {
>               // Error handling goes here.
>           }
>           public void onMapContentComplete() {
>           }
>       };
>
>       mapCanvas.getMapDisplay().setState(
>           new MapDisplayState(new GeoCoordinate(52.51, 13.4, 0), 10));
>
>       System.out.println(mapCanvas.getMapDisplay().getState());
>
>       display.setCurrent(mapCanvas);
>
>       System.out.println("END");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally the most elegant way would be to create a custom LWUIT component which **encapsulates** the `MapCanvas` and exposes a standard LWUIT interface - in other words basic use of an adaptor pattern. There is an example of this pattern to be found within the Nokia Projects [Tourist Attractions](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/LWUIT_TouristAttractions) example (the version updated for LWUIT). Additionally sample code for such a component can be found on GIT hub [here](https://github.com/gorkem/com.gorkem_ercan.lwuit.map)